# Question about truncating Taylor expansion and absorb the rest in a big Oh bound

Tags: analysis, inequality, proof-explanation, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I am studying the proof of the below Lemma and have some questions regarding the bounds for truncated Taylor expansion.

We take $N$ some large number and $1\le M \le N \le t$ and $r=\frac{5.01 \log t}{\log N}$ which is just some number to get the bound. $x$ and $y$ are just some dummy variables set up so that when we take the sum $\sum_{N<n\le N+M} n^{-it}$ we have $xy/n \le N^{-1/5}$.

The question I have here is when we apply Taylor expansion to $\log(1+\frac{xy}{n})$ why do we get $$\log(1+\frac{xy}{n})=\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor r \rfloor} \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j}(\frac{xy}{n})^j + O\big((\frac{xy}{n})^{5.01(\log t)/\log N}\big),$$ i.e. how can we just truncate the logarithm to the first $r$ terms and bound the rest by $(\frac{xy}{n})^{r}$? This isn't even the $\lfloor r \rfloor +1$th term of the Taylor expansion so I am not sure where this bound comes from.

Finally, the reason we do this expansion for $\log$ is actually because we apply it to $(1+xy/n)^{-it}=e^{-it \log(1+\frac{xy}{n})}.$ Because we have $xy/n \le N^{-1/5}$ we have $O\big((\frac{xy}{n})^{5.01(\log t)/\log N}\big) = O(t^{-1/500})$. And for the last part of the proof we use the fact that $\exp\{O(t^{-1/500})\} = 1 + O(t^{-1/500})$. Why can we absorb the infinite sum of the terms by the first order of the Taylor expansion?

I thought the second result could hold because if we let $a=t^{-1/500}$ then the remaining sum after the first term is $t^{-1/500} + t^{-2/500}/2! + t^{-3/500}/3!+\cdots$ but this is $\ll a+a^2+ a^3 +\cdots = a(1+a+a^2+\cdots)$ where $a<1$ and hence by geometric progression the infinite sum inside the bracket converges to $1/(1-a)$. But this is not a constant and depends on $a$ so how can I show it gets swallowed into the $O(a)$ bound? I think the bound for logarithm can be achieved similarly but then I run into the same problem.

**Update** I think my method works here because we assume $t$ is a very large number so we have some constant $c$ that is $1<c<t^{1/500}$ then $t^{-1500}=a<1/c<1$ hence we can bound $1+a+a^2+\cdots $ by $1+1/c+1/c^2 + \cdots = 1/(1-1/c)$ which is just a constant.

Now we can do something similar for the logarithm case as we have $xy/n \le N^{-1/5}$ so again we can treat $(xy/n)^j$ part as a geometric progression and in fact this is a worse case than the given sum because with the $1/j$ term the series would converge faster. Then similarly we should get the bound by the next term $O((\frac{xy}{n}^{\lfloor r \rfloor + 1}))$ but since $xy/n <1 $, we should have $\{xy/n\}^{\lfloor r \rfloor + 1} \le \{xy/n\}^r$ which gives the result of the Lemma.

I would greatly appreciate if someone verify my reasoning or suggest something else. I have looked at the Taylor estimate for the remainder in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Estimates_for_the_remainder but I don't understand how this can be applied here without a clear context on where the intervals for the function is in and the lower and upper bound for the next order derivative.

[image]

Comment: $|e(z)| = |e^{2\pi i z}| = 1$ for real $z$.  Or do you not want the $i$ ?

Comment: Big $O$ in what sense?  You just say "for some $t \ge 1$".  So it is not $t \to 0$ or $t \to \infty$ ??

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry it is just the $\exp$ function I believe the context is $t\to \infty$. I have updated the question there is actually a similar one regarding the Taylor expansion of the logarithm. I would appreciate a lot if you could answer these questions.

Comment: See `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Estimates_for_the_remainder`  This should be in almost all calculus textbooks.

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry I don't see how we can use this estimate here we don't have a specific bounded interval given and have lower and upper bounds for the (k+1)th derivative. I was thinking the result could hold because if we let $a=t^{-1/500}$ then the remaining sum $t^{-2/500} + t^{-3/500}+\cdots = a(a+a^2+\cdots)$ where $a<1$ and hence the infinite sum inside converges and gets swallowed into the $O(a)$ bound. I think the bound for logarithm can be achieved similarly but I'm having difficulty finding out why we can get rid of $(-1)^{j-1}/j$ and bound by the $r$th power and not the $r+1$th power.

Comment: Actually the remaining sums should be like $a^2/2! + a^3/3!+\cdots$ but we can bound them to get rid of the factorials and they should still converge by geometric progression.

Answer (score 1):

The other terms are
$O(t^{-k/500})$
for $k \ge 2$
and these are swallowed up by
$O(t^{-1/500})$.

Comment: Could you check my updated question?